# Firebase: Retrieving multiple nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to retrieve multiple nodes separated by commas from Firebase?

For example, get the `name` and `image` properties of an user using:

`/users/$USER_ID/name,image`

instead of downloading all the user information

Comment: If you are willing to use 2 network calls, you can child directly into each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase SDK always retrieves complete nodes from the database. There is no way to select a subset of the nodes.

If you find you want a subset of the nodes and that downloading all nodes would be overly wasteful, you should model your data to have an additional collection where you only keep the properties you want for each user:

```
user
  uid1
    name: "TheUnreal"
    image: "https://graph.facebook.com/1214076718653094/picture?type=large"
    stackid: 3669981
    lastquestionid: 40565750
  uid2
    name: "Frank van Puffelen"
    image: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12d378e6a9788ab9c94bbafe242b82b4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG"
    stackid: 209103
    lastquestionid: 39984247
users_names_images
  uid1
    name: "TheUnreal"
    image: "https://graph.facebook.com/1214076718653094/picture?type=large"
  uid2
    name: "Frank van Puffelen"
    image: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12d378e6a9788ab9c94bbafe242b82b4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG"
```

With this data structure you can choose whether you get a subset of the data or the complete data by querying the corresponding top-level node. Duplicating data like this is fairly common in NoSQL databases, where you often model the data for how your app consumes it.

Comment: That's the only way around I thought about, but the drawback is updating those 2 nodes whenever user updates his image or name. If I could just pick the nodes I want, there was no need in extra node. I've been thinking about sending a feature request to Firebase about that but it might encourage to build the database structure differently

Comment: *disclosure: I work on Firebase* Definitely [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). But even if we decide to implement it at some point, that won't help you today. Duplicating data is completely normal in NoSQL databases such as Firebase and is part of the reason they scale so well.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the nodes using a class. I do it like that. Why don't you manipulate the returned values so as to make it in a way you'd be able to use.